# Format UTC date and time in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date, time, date-pipe

I am trying to change just the UTC time and date format which I am receiving from backend.I tried datepipe to format the UTC time but it automatically converting the time to my local browser time.
I want to show the same time which the backend sends.

I tried like below.

time = this.datepipe.transform(result.time,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" "UTC")

Comment: I want to just append UTC at end of all the timestamps.
format the time like "2022-09-01 03:24:23 UTC" instead of showing like "2022-09-01T03:24:23.000Z"

Comment: Your code works just fine... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1r6d4z?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It's working!Thankd for your help I am struggling from morning.The problem is I missed comma in bwt the format and utc.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript code:

```
time = this.datepipe.transform(result.time,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" | '+0000'")
```

Use this way on HTML

```
{{result.time | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a' : '+0000'}}
```

Comment: " | " instead of " , " ("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" , "+0000" )